# Azure SQL databse: bacpac Import Error occurs on azure portal

Tags: sql-server, azure, azureportal

I have exported a data-tier application from on-premise and trying import from azure portal on a new database. But it keeps failing, I am not sure whether the following error message is truncated but I feel it is missing something. Any help is appreciated. This happens while importing a .bacpac to azure SQL.

```
   {
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": "The ImportExport operation with Request Id '3d73223b-acff-4c6e-a981-39d27234d89d' failed due to 'Could not import package.\nWarning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.\nWarning SQL72012: The object [data_0] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.\nWarning SQL72012: The object [log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you '."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to migrate data to Azure SQL. It will asses database first to make sure it is compatible. Then it is going to guide you through migration process - it will also tell you what to do if there are some compatibility issues.

Comment: Hi Kamil, Thanks for the suggestion. I had used DMA and found no compatibility issues there.

Answer (score 0):

As guessed earlier, the error message was truncated in azure portal. There was a third error which was about a column name being duplicated in a view. I imported same bacpac file on my local sql server then I was able to view all the import errors there without being truncated. Thanks